# Time Synchronizer hangs after few messages

Tags: ros, synchronization, message-filters, timesynchronizer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`enter code here`Hi,

I have a scenario where I have 2 sensors publishing messages to 2 different topics, let's say:

topicA

topicB

I wanted to subscribe to both these topics using a 3rd node; compare the values from the first 2 topics and do certain operations and generate a new output to be published onto another topic say,

topicC

For this I created custom messages for each of my sensors with a header containing the time stamp.

In the nodes publishing to topics 'topicA' and 'topicB' I initialized the timestamp field in the header as

> x.header.timeStamp = ros::Time::now()

All my publisher nodes run continuously with no problems. However, I only get the first two messages at the output of my synchronizer and then it stops forever. Then I am unable to stop the node other than terminating the execution using SIGINT (ctrl+z).

Can someone tell me what I can do so that my timesynchronizer works properly and synchronizes the outputs from topicA and topicB using timestamps.

Here's the code of node 3:

```
void fusionCallback(const fusion::TwistsConstPtr& sensorA, const fusion::TwistsConstPtr& sensorB)
geometry_msgs::Twist vel;
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher vel_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 1);
ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
while(ros::ok())
{
    float sensorA_dat = sensorA->dat;
    float sensorB_dat = sensorB->dat;
    if(sensorB_dat > sensorA_dat)
        vel = sensorB->vel;
    else vel = sensorA->vel;
    vel_pub.publish(vel);
    ROS_INFO("sensorA Data = [%f] sensorB Data = [%f]", sensorA_dat, sensorB_dat);
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
```

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "vel_publisher");
ros::NodeHandle n;
//ros::Rate loop_rate(20);

using namespace message_filters;
Subscriber<fusion::Twists> sensorA_sub(n, "/fusion/cmd_vel_sensorA", 1);
Subscriber<fusion::Twists> sensorB_sub(n, "/fusion/cmd_vel_sensorB", 1);


typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<fusion::Twists, fusion::Twists> MySyncPolicy;

Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(100), sensorA_sub, sensorB_sub);
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&fusionCallback, _1, _2));
ros::spin();

return 0;
```

}

Note: All braces are proper in the actual code!

### Update : The Effect of spin inside callback

On the suggestion of @dornhege I tried removing the spin inside callback and then my code started working. I was able to see the output wherein the TimeSynchronizer merged the data from both the topics appropriately. I was able to terminate the execution using ctrl+c as well.

However, the problem is that now my output is not getting published. Infact, that is the reason why I have the spin inside the callback. This is as per the basic tutorials for publisher and subscriber provided [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

Thanks and Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43088/time-synchronizer-hangs-after-few-messages/) by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 612 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-09-05**:
Can you post a miminal excerpt of your program showing how is your main loop? If ctrl+z do not have any effect, then you probably do not look for ros::ok() enough and you may have spin issues which prevent the callbacks from being called several times. You can also increase the queue. It may help.

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-09-05**:
As far as ctrl+z is concerned i have said in my question that it is the only thing that is able to stop my program.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-05**:
Your code looks like you are starting another ROS spinning loop within the callback. Is that really what you want, it seems very odd.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-05**:
Ctrl-C should be SIGINT, Ctrl-z does something different. Ctrl-C should stop a program that check's ros::ok.

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-09-06**:
Oh yeah am sorry. I think ctrl+z is SIGTERM or SIGSTOP. am not sure. But anyways ctrl+c does not stop the running program.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-06**:
On the publishing: 1. a spin won't help there. 2. Are you still constructing the publisher in the callback? That is the problem. It needs time to connect the topic and actually be able to publish -> only construct one in the main, that should help. The spin was functioning as a "wait loop" for that.

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-09-06**:
Heyy @dornhege thanks a lot lot lot!! It worked. I actually tried this before as well after referring another answer in ros. But I made a silly mistake of initializing the publisher twice and then it gave me a runtime error of invalid publisher. So I thought maybe I was wrong.

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-09-06**:
But now I decided it must be right since you've told as well and tried to work on finding the mistake and now its found. Thanks Again :) Its all good now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### This answer is based on suggestions from @dornhege

It is important to note that a spin need not be added in a publisher that is called from within a callback.

1. Remove the spin instruction and the while loop from the publisher.
2. Declare publisher globally.
3. define the publisher inside the main.
4. (if needed) Add a small sleep routine to let the publisher get ready to send data. (ros::Duration(0.1).sleep();)

Here is the modified code

```
    ros::Publisher vel_pub;
void fusionCallback(const fusion::TwistsConstPtr& sensorA, const fusion::TwistsConstPtr& sensorB)
{
geometry_msgs::Twist vel;


ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
float sensorA_dat = sensorA->dat;
float sensorB_dat = sensorB->dat;
if(sensorB_dat > sensorA_dat)
    vel = sensorB->vel;
else vel = sensorA->vel;
vel_pub.publish(vel);
ROS_INFO("sensorA Data = [%f] sensorB Data = [%f]", sensorA_dat, sensorB_dat);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "vel_publisher");
ros::NodeHandle n;
//ros::Rate loop_rate(20);
vel_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 1);
using namespace message_filters;
Subscriber<fusion::Twists> sensorA_sub(n, "/fusion/cmd_vel_sensorA", 1);
Subscriber<fusion::Twists> sensorB_sub(n, "/fusion/cmd_vel_sensorB", 1);


typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<fusion::Twists, fusion::Twists> MySyncPolicy;

Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(100), sensorA_sub, sensorB_sub);
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&fusionCallback, _1, _2));
ros::spin();

return 0;
}
```

Thanks Again @dornhege.

Hope this helps anyone who may find a similar problem with TimeSynchronizer.

Regards,

---

Originally posted by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) with karma: 612 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TimeSynchronizer synchronizes by exact timestamps. If you generated them from sensors it's very unlikely to find a match. You should try the policy base synchronizer with ApproximateTimePolicy.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-09-05**:
That was what I did in order to see if that would work. but it did not help me either. do you have an alternative suggestion?